Is it possible to make a circle like LoopTools but only one quarter of it?
I'm trying to find a fast way to model the edges to quarter of a circle. Quarter of what LoopTools > Circle does. Currently I do LoopTools > Circle

Then this is the result but I only want the green region to be affected.

Right now I manually straighten back the edges by first setting transform pivot to 3d cursor then putting the 3d cursor on a spot I know to be the reference and select the edge loop and then scale to zero. I do this manually for all edge loops but that is a bit tedious especially if I have more subdivisions so I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this? Something that does LoopTools > Quarter Circle or something?



In Edit Mode, on  2D geometry, Shift Alt S 'To Sphere' will normalize the selection about the current Transform Pivot Point to a circle.
(Here, the pivot is '3D cursor'):

.. For even distribution of vertices, you can use the shipped add-on Loop tools > Space
Stripping out the arc, duplicating at scales, and comparing with a curve, shows that the approximation is very reasonable under mirroring and subdivision:


thank you for your answer! looks like the most efficient way to do things
